# Correct way to import functions from file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a simple python3 CLI for some scripting. I have troubles importing my own functions located in files that are in the same modules.

My file structure is

```
pycli/
├── README.md
├── pycli
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── cli.py
  └── funcmodule.py
```

`funcmodule.py`:

```
def my_function(word):
    print("Hello %s" % word)
```

`cli.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pycli.funcmodule import my_function


def main():
    my_function('hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run `./pycli/cli.py` from the command line I get

```
(venv) ➜  ./pycli/cli.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pycli/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pycli.funcmodule import my_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycli'
```

When I run the `cli.py` from PyCharm or in Visual Studio Code, it works correctly. What is the correct way to import the function with python3+ (I don't care about python2)?

Comment: Because both of them are in the same directory you can try `from funcmodule import my_function`  instead of `from pycli.funcmodule import my_function` in `cli.py`.

Comment: running the script in the `pycli` dir should also fix the issue

Comment: This works but when I do so, the IDEs intelli sense report errors `Unresolved reference 'funcmodule' ` and `Unresolved reference 'my_function' `

Comment: Have a look at ``entry_points`` and their ``console_scripts``. Putting a script directly inside a library is generally not a good idea (for the reasons you are seeing).

Comment: What is the `pycli` in `pycli ./pycli/cli.py`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica sorry that was just the pwd of the shell prompt

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but I want my script to be the library. i.e. I want eventually ship this cli as my internal tool and install it via pip on other servers

Comment: @Jan ``console_scripts`` exists *exactly* for the purpose of properly creating scripts during library installation.

Comment: you can create your own file in pycli folder say abc , which import main from cli.py and then run the program from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mismatch between how you're running the program and how your imports are set up. Your imports are set up as if there's a package involved, but you're running the program like there's no package.

The way you're running your program, the contents of the inner `pycli` folder are all top-level modules, and there is no `pycli` package. To run your program as a package submodule, you need to do so from somewhere the `pycli` package is importable (which, as things are, would be inside the outer `pycli` folder, but could be anywhere if you installed your package), and you need to run

```
python -m pycli.cli
```

Comment: accepted as answer. I also added my own answer where I install the entire package but this is basically what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

So what I needed is to create a proper package with the `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = 'pycli',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages = ['pycli'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'pycli = pycli.cli:main'
        ]
    })
```

in order to run it from the terminal

```
pip3 install .

pycli
Hello hello world
```